# Equivalents of the name Danila

Tags: выбор-имени

My Russian friend is teasing with his name. He says friends call him Danila, but it is not his real name.

He told me to substitute one letter in the name Danila to get it right, but I have no idea how and which.

I tried to Google similar names, but I didn't find it.

Can anyone help me to find which letter do I substitute to find a valid male Russian name?

Comment: It might be Санила (a very colloquial form of Саня which is a form of Александр). Or Ванила (a very colloquial and almost artificial form of Ваня which is a form of Иван).  No ideas beyond these two.

Comment: Try Даниил , which is almost the same name.

Comment: A litte(child) Danila (Данила, Даниил) also can be called as "Даня".

Answer (score 2):

**Дании́л** (Дани́л, Дани́ла) — are different variations of the same name.So I think this is the name you are looking for.Даниил is the name of one of the prophets in the Bible. You need to change the last a into и . Friends can call him Данила,but officially he is Даниил.

Comment: But this would actually make two-letters difference, wouldn't it?

Comment: @bipil. The last. "A" is changed into " и", that makes **one** letter  actually, and is placed before "л."

Comment: That makes two steps of transformation, moreover not every definition of Levenstein distance allows letter swaps.

Comment: It can also be Данило. A somewhat archaic variation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend with officialy name ***Данил*** and he rejects other forms like ***Данила*** or ***Даниил***.